# AWS cloud #VPC SUBNET

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, private-subnet

My question is when we planning to have fully AWS managed service in private subnet [VPC]. Then the service will become fully managed or user has to manage it?

Ex: Planning to have AWS RDS in a private subnet, who will maintain the RDS?

Thanks,
MD

Comment: This will most likely end up being [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), as it relates to professional networking infrastructure and is not necessarily about programming. You might be able to find an answer on [sf], but please keep in mind [what topics you can ask about there](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

By having resources in private subnets it just prevents public ingress via the internet.

Ownership of the [shared responsibility model](https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/shared-responsibility-model/) does not change.